# Wrapper Module for two Applications

Tags: c++, class, shared-libraries, wrapper, lib

I have two static libs Lib-1 and Lib-2. Lib-1 is for windows and Lib-2 is for Linux. Also I have two application App-1 and App-2 which can be ported for windows as well as in linux. Both applications need to access either Lib-1 or Lib-2 according to the platform on which applications are running. The intention is the application should wrap the Lib-1 and Lib-2 implementation (something like wrapper) and shall be easily configurable for windows and linux.

The scenario is something similar below

```
Third Party Lib-1 (Windows)
---------------------------
void CalculateForLinux();

Third Party Lib-2 (Linux)
--------------------------
void CalculateForWindows();

Application-1 (Portable for windows and linux) - Currently running for Windows
----------------------------------------------
Class WrapperLib {
     int m_platform; //0 for linux and 1 for windows
     WrapperLib(int platform) : m_platform(platform); 
     public:
         Calculate() {
             if (m_platform) {
                 CalculateForWindows();
             }
             else {
                 CalculateForLinux();
             } 
         }
} 
SomeFunctionInApp1()
{
     WrapperLib lib(1); //for windows
     lib.Calculate();
}

And Application 2 Code below

Application-2 (Portable for windows and linux) - Currently running for Windows
----------------------------------------------
Class WrapperLib {
     int m_platform; //0 for linux and 1 for windows
     WrapperLib(int platform) : m_platform(platform); 
     public:
         Calculate() {
             if (m_platform) {
                 CalculateForWindows();
             }
             else {
                 CalculateForLinux();
             } 
         }
} 
SomeFunctioninApp2()
{
    WrapperLib lib(1); //for windows 
    lib.Calculate();
}
```

Here whether this scenario can be written in a better way ?

I need to avoid writing wrapper implementation in both Application 1 and 2. Is there any better way to achieve this ? What about making the wrapper implementation itself a library. So it would be a library over a library. Is that a good way here ?

Comment: Is it possible to expose the exact same interface from both platform-specific libraries? Then you can simply link with the appropriate module for your platform.

Comment: @Botje, Unfortunately not. Both libraries are third party libs and interface is different for platforms.

Comment: _What about making the wrapper implementation itself a library. So it would be a library over a library. Is that a good way here ?_ It's definitely one possible way. It has been done before for other subjects (if I only could remember when and where I saw one).